# How to let django user authenticate linux user

Tags: django, authentication

Here is the problem: I use django pam to let django able to authenticate linux users but it can only be run as root. Is there any solutions to let normal user able to authenticate lunux users?

Comment: Can you provide more info (errors you get)? Using pam module I can authenticate any user...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit round about, but I imagine it would work.

Assuming a debian distro, you could try adding the specific command that you want to a script, then chmod/chown it to restrict access to root only.

```
chown root:root /path/to/script.sh
chmod 755 /path/to/script.sh
```

Next, run `sudo visudo` and add the following:

```
normalusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/usr/path/to/script.sh
```

Reboot, write some code in python to execute your script as a normal user, and I imagine you'd be good to go.

Your python code would look like this:

```
import os
os.system("sudo path/to/script.sh")
```